# Is it possible to turn permissions on and off through API

Tags: force.com, api, administration

Is it possible to turn permissions on and off in Salesforce through API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can change Salesforce profiles and PermissionSets through Metadata API. Please find below are the links for salesforce documentation with Sample code and Sample XML data to be sent out

Profiles - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_profile.htm

PermissionSet - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_permissionset.htm

Java Code sample to use API - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_calls_intro.htm#title_java_sample_code_SOAP